# Add ActionLink to Default MVC Web Application

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created a HelloWorld Controller and it's corresponding view.  All is working correctly when I go to `http://localhost/HelloWorld`

I am trying to add a menu item to the default MVC app.  In the _Layout.cshtml file I have

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Hello World", "HelloWorld", "")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
</ul>
```

Note they only thing I added was the Hello World part.  However when I click on the menu item it takes me `http://localhost/Home/HelloWorld`.  How do I get it to go to just `http://localhost/HelloWorld`?

I'm really new to MVC and not exactly sure what I'm doing.  A few google searches have mentioned modifying the Routes in the Global.asax.cs but that seems a bit weird and not sure where to start there.  I've also tried using the ~ to get back to root which works in the old school asp.net pages but not here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition for `ActionLink` is.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName
)
```

Since you are trying to redirect to `/HelloWorld`, I'm assuming that your controller is `HelloWorld` and your action is `Index`.  Using this information we can fill in the method.

```
Html.ActionLink(
    "Hello World",  // Link Text
    "Index",        // Action
    "HelloWorld",   // Controller
)
```

Comment: To easy.  Amateur mistake.  Can't accept until 7 mins has past though.  Will accept in a few mins.  Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.  Sometimes we are so tired even the simplest things are difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for ActionLink that you want is:

```
@Html.ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName)
```

You're passing in the ActionName and leaving the controllerName blank, which by default will assume it's an Action on the current controller (in this case, "Home").

try

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hello World", "HelloWorld", "HelloWorld")
```

assuming, that is, that `HelloWorld` in the name of the *Action* on your `HellowWorldController`.   If the Action is something different, replace the second parameter with the appropriate name.

Comment: Since he wants the URL to be `/HelloWorld` the action **has** to be `Index`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use empty strings:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "", "")

@Html.ActionLink("About Us", "About", "Home")

@Html.ActionLink("Contact me", "Contact", "Home")
```